# Respond.getRequestDispatcher() not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, setattribute

well I tried to send information from a servlet to jsp so I try using request.setAttribute() and respond.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp") it says method not found (getRequestDispatcher()) I also tried with sessions but I don't know how to kill the session or how to reset variables, 
Help please, Thanks!!!!

here is some code:

This didn't work:

```
req.setAttribute("usuario_incorrecto", "Nombre de Usuario o Contraseña incorrecto");
response.getRequestDispatcher("perfil.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

So I tried using this:

```
HttpSession sess = req.getSession(); 
sess.setAttribute("usuario_incorrecto", "Nombre de Usuario o Contraseña incorrecto");
```

and this works but I need to clear it inmediately after using it... 
I got it from jps with

```
${usuario_incorrecto}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get the RequestDispatcher on the HttpServletRequest object, not on the HttpServletResponse as I see in your code, try something like this-

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("pathToResource");
  rd.forward(request, response);
}
```